MIPS32, global variable being overwritten
In the following code, at the instructions:
  la $t0, suma
  sw $t2, ($t0)
  lw $a1, ($t0)
  la $t1, najmanji
  sh $t4, ($t1)

, the second la instruction loads addres of symbol najmanji and it ends up being the same address as for symbol suma, debugging in gdb I saw that after the last sh instruction suma gets overwritten. Why does that happen? Why are the addresses of two different symbols the same? The print ends up being correct because I'm loading it into the a registers sequentially, but still I am interested how does memory work?
.section .data
.global niz
niz: .short 12, 3, -9, 1200, -2400, 490, 800, -23, 5 , 22
.section .rodata
.global str
str: .string "Suma: %d\nNajmanji: %d\n"
.section .bss
.global suma
suma: .word
.global najmanji
najmanji: .short 
.section .text
.global main 
main:
  addiu $t0, $0, 10 // size
  addu $t1, $0, $0 // i = 0
  addu $t2, $0, $0 // suma_ = 0

  la $t3, niz // &niz
  lh $t4, ($t3) // najmanji_ = niz[0]
  
  while:
    slt $t5, $t1, $t0
    beq $t5, $0, iskoci
    sll $t6, $t1, 1
    addu $t6, $t3, $t6
    lh $t6, ($t6)
    addu $t2, $t2, $t6
    slt $t7, $t6, $t4
    beq $t7, $0, preskoci
    addu $t4, $0, $t6 
    preskoci:
    addiu $t1, $t1, 1
  j while 

  iskoci:
  la $t0, suma
  sw $t2, ($t0)
  lw $a1, ($t0)
  la $t1, najmanji
  sh $t4, ($t1)
  lh $a2, ($t1)
  la $a0, str 
  addiu $sp, $sp, -24
  sw $ra, 20($sp)
  jal printf
  lw $ra, 20($sp)
  addiu $sp, $sp, 24
  addu $v0, $0, $0
  jr $ra


I believe your assembler is skipping your .word definition (not reserving space) because you didn't provide an initial value. Try using suma: .word 0 and najmanji: .short 0

Many studying assembly language are either unaware or forget that data can be debugged/analyzed as well as (single stepping to debug) the code.  Of course, if either data or code are incorrect, likely problems.  Get to know your data, look at the layout of data, values of labels, etc.  This helps when single stepping the code because you already know what good pointer values look like.
